# PySpark na.fill not replacing null values with 0 in DF

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I am using the following code sample:

```
paths = ["/FileStore/tables/data.csv"]

infer_schema = "true"
df= sqlContext.read \
       .format("com.databricks.spark.csv") \
       .option("inferSchema", infer_schema) \
       .option("header", "true") \
       .load(paths)

df.printSchema()
```

> root  |-- key: string (nullable = true)  |-- dt:
> string (nullable = true)  |-- key1: string (nullable =
> true)  |-- key2: string (nullable = true)  |-- sls: string
> (nullable = true)  |-- uts: string (nullable = true)  |-- key3:
> string (nullable = true)

I did the following to count the null values for the fields `sls` and `uts`

```
df.select([count(when(col(c).isNull(), c)).alias(c) for c in df.columns]).show()

+-------------+--------+------------------+-----------+-----+-----+---------+
|key|           dt|        key1|             key2|      sls|  uts|   key3|
+-------------+--------+------------------+-----------+-----+-----+---------+
|            0|       0|                 0|          0|  616|  593|        0|
+-------------+--------+------------------+-----------+-----+-----+---------+
```

I did the following first:

```
df.na.fill({'sls': 0, 'uts': 0})
```

Then I realized these are string fields. So, I did:

```
df.na.fill({'sls': '0', 'uts': '0'})
```

After doing this, if I do :

```
df.filter("sls is NULL").show()
```

I see `null` values for `sls` field:

```
key|              dt|      key1|             key2|       sls|   uts|  key3|
+-------------+----------+------------------+-----------+-----+-----+-----------+
|           -1| 7/13/2020|              8000|41342299215| null|    1|1.70228E+25|
|           -1| 12/5/2019|              8734| 8983349833| null|    1|1.76412E+26|
|           -1|  1/7/2020|              8822|      1E+15| null|    1|4.69408E+24|
|           -1| 12/5/2018|              6768|      1E+15| null|    1|4.54778E+24|
```

It's the same thing if I do:

```
df.filter("uts is NULL").show()
```

Is there something I am missing? Why am I unable to replace the null values with `0`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`.na.fill` returns a new data frame with null values being replaced. You just need to assign the result to `df` variable in order for the replacement to take effect:

```
df = df.na.fill({'sls': '0', 'uts': '0'})
```